# How to pack widgets towards the vertical center of a window in PyGTK?

Tags: python, layout, pygtk

I am using PyGTK to create a GUI:

```
vbox = gtk.VBox(False, 1)
vbox.set_border_width(1)
window.add(vbox)
vbox.show()

vbox.pack_start(menubar, False, True, 0)
vbox.pack_start(a, False, False, 0)
vbox.pack_start(b, False, False, 10)
vbox.pack_end(self.statusbar, False, False, 0)
vbox.pack_end(c, False, False, 10)
```

- `a` and `b` are fixed-sized elements.

This creates a window like this:

```
 _______________________
|_Window____________|_X_|
|_File_Edit_____________|
|          [a]          |
|          [b]          |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|__________[c]__________|
|__Status okay._________|
```

I need to center `a` and `b` vertically, so that the bottom edge of `a` appears at vertical center and the top edge of `b` appears at the vertical center:

```
 _______________________
|_Window____________|_X_|
|_File_Edit_____________|
|                       |
|           |           |
|           v           |
|          [a]          |
|                       |<-- 10 px margin
|          [b]          |
|           ^           |
|           |           |
|                       |
|__________[c]__________|
|__Status okay._________|
```

- Within PyQT4, this layout can be achieved by adding `addStretch(1)` to the spaces before and after these items, but I cannot find an equivalent command for PyGTK.
- Center can be measured as the space between the file menu and the status bar or the space between the file menu and [c], whichever solution is simplest.

Is there a way to vertically center the items in a window in this way?

Answer (score 2):

You must using second VBox to pack a & b widgets together and then pack this box center, run below code:

```
import gtk

window = gtk.Window()
window.set_size_request(120, 180)

vbox = gtk.VBox()
vbox.set_border_width(1)
window.add(vbox)
vbox.show()

a = gtk.Label('a')
b = gtk.Label('b')
c = gtk.Label('c')

vbox2 = gtk.VBox()
vbox2.pack_start(a, True, False, 0)
vbox2.pack_start(b, True, False, 10)
vbox.pack_start(vbox2, True, False, 10)
vbox.pack_end(c, False, False, 10)

window.connect('destroy', gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

The `Pack_start` and `pack_end` methods getting some parameters to set position of your widgets.

```
pack_start(widget?, center?, max_stretch?, border?)
```